# Border-image and CSS image not lining up in Firefox only

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

I have a table where the cells all have a 1px top-border, except the first column, which has a background image to replicate a 1px bottom border (the border fades out to the left). In all browsers (Chrome, Safari, IE6+) the 'fake border' lines up with the 'real border' - except in Firefox, where the fake border is 1px too low. If I manually move the image 1px up, it disappears altogether.

I imagine that Firefox handle the extra 1px border differently. If there is a cell with a border next to a cell without a border, Firefox seems to leave a space where the border should be, whereas other browsers expand the border-less cell by 1px, so my images can take up that space. (I hope that makes sense!)

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Working example: http://resonantmind.net/temp/compare.php

Comment: Your code or an example would be helpful.

Comment: Can you link to the actual page? The example code doesn't seem to exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Here's a working example from my code: http://resonantmind.net/temp/compare.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** I tried the `-1px` as well but I set the height to `50px`. Not exactly what you want but seems to be on the right path.

```
.compare .item {
    background:#fcfcfc url(bg-compare-item.gif) no-repeat 0 -1px;
    height:50px;

    /* original */
    text-align:left; line-height:29px !important; border:0;
}
```

**2.** Another solution is to shift the top line on the image down 1px and completely remove the bottom line. Then have the `-1px` in the CSS and you'll get the desired results. Looks good in Chome, IE9, and Firefox.

Comment: I couldn't get your solution to work across all browsers, so I've used something similar with a Firefox-specific rule (I am using a JS that adds a class to the body depending on what browser you load the page in). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find an overall solution. Glad I could help and you found a solution that works. Btw, you should post you solution so other's can use it if they come across the same problem.

Comment: My solution involved changing the images for Firefox and IE, so that the line was at the bottom of the image instead of the top. A bit hacky, but it worked.